# Can we add attribute(i.e. id/class) on any div which is inside the <script type="text/template" id="template"><script>

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates

I want to add the class attribute on `#new-post` which is content of `<script type="text/template" id="template"></script>`

Below is my code which is able to find the content of 'template' but not able to add the class attribute.

```
$('#template').contents().find('#new-post').addClass('hello');
```

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/template" id="template">
   <div id="new-post">
   &nbsp;
   </div>
</script>
```

Comment: But not able to add class attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A script element contains CDATA, it cannot have child elements (`<` does not mean "start of tag" inside it (except when that tag is `</script>`)).

If you want to perform DOM manipulation of the contents of your template, then you must first parse the template into a DOM.

```
var template = $('#template').text(); 
var $template = $(template);
$template.addClass('hello');
alert($template.wrap('<div></div>').parent().html());
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you render the template to the dom and then add the class.

**Edit:**
Please note that your code doesn't work even if the div is inside a normal html tag.

Please refer this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/shyamchandranmec/R7g3S/

```
$('#foo').contents().find('#bar').addClass('fb');
$("#foo").find("#bar").addClass('foobar');

<div id="foo">
    <div id="bar">foo bar</div>
</div>
```

The class fb wont be added to the div #bar.

Comment: It can be done...but why we cann't do the changes within the template

Comment: @Konza-I can do this with the rendered html but question is , why we cann't do changes inside <script type="text/template" id="template">
   <div id="new-post">
   &nbsp;
   </div>
</script>